# How deploy a cube (XMLA format) on an Azure SSAS

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, ssas

Good afternoon everybody,

First I wish you the best for 2021 and even 2022
Here is my problem, I'm waiting our technical team grant me access to the Azure Devops platform (this can take a while), but in the meanwhile I would like to have a temporary solution allowing me to deploy an xmla (Json format) directly on an existing SSAS instance in order to create a cube using powershell.

I've read some documentation and it seems the best solution is to use the Invoke-ASCmd (correct me if I'm wrong); and I don't think it's possible to do that through REST API

Idea is to create a new cube in an automated way

Here is my code

```
$myfile = "c:\temp\test2.xmla"
$mybody=Get-Content -Path c:\temp\test2.xmla
$myaas="asazure://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/pocenvironment"
$myaasname="pocenvironment"
$mytenant = "1234"
$myclientID = "ABCD";
$mykeyID = "theKeyID";
$myauthority = "https://login.windows.net/" + $mytenant + "/oauth2/authorize";

$TokenRequestParams = @{
    Method = 'POST'
    Uri    = "$myauthority"
    Body   = @{
        grant_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
        code       = $DeviceCodeRequest.device_code
        client_id  = $myclientID
    }
}
$TokenRequest = Invoke-RestMethod @TokenRequestParams

$myconnectstr="Provider=MSOLAP;User ID=;Password="+$TokenRequest+";Data Source="+$myaas+";Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate"

Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile $myfile -ConnectionString $myconnectstr -Server $myaas
```

and the XMLA is something like this

```
{
  "create": {
    "database": {
      "name": "TESTME",
      "compatibilityLevel": 1500,
      "model": {
        "culture": "en-GB",
        "dataSources": [
          
        ],
        "tables": [
           
        ],
        "relationships": [
          
        ],
        "roles": [
          {
            "name": "Admin",
            "modelPermission": "administrator",
            "members": [
              {
                "memberName": "myemail@domain.com",
                "identityProvider": "AzureAD"
              }
                     ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Reader",
            "modelPermission": "read",
            "members": [
              
            ]
          }
        ],
        "annotations": [
          {
            "name": "ClientCompatibilityLevel",
            "value": "400"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I receive the following error message (tried with the powershell ise x86 and 64bits)

```
<b>Invoke-ASCmd : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:24 char:1
+ Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile $myfile -ConnectionString $myconnectstr -Serv ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ASCmd], NullReferenceE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Analysis 
   Services.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExecuteScriptCommand
</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found and fix
In fact the powershell module sqlserver does not run correctly with version 20 but version 21 allow to select the -tenantid.

No more error , deployment running smoothly :)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying something similar to "createoreplace" multiple tables on Azure AAS Tabular Model, in my case $connectionstring was a problem, if you have not already tried, try authenticating first with your id .. Thanks

Comment: If I add my uid/pwd I've got the same error message. Did you were able to have a solution on your side ? Which connection string do you used ?

Invoke-ASCmd : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Pre-requisite:
Install-Module -Name Az.AnalysisServices

Connect-AzAccount

Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Invoke-ASCmd -Server:asazure://xxregionxx.asazure.windows.net/xxservernamexx -Database:xxDbNamexx -InputFile:"C:\temp\temp.xmla"

--This Step should prompt for Authentication of AzAccount used in first step

In my case the there were 2 issues Service Principal did not have permissions on AAS Server and then the Token concatenate was incorrect to form connectionstring, above mentioned steps helped me to verify if the script was working

Comment: [link](https://medium.com/swlh/you-me-ci-cd-deploying-azure-analysis-services-tabular-models-through-azure-pipelines-55370ac9fab3), this is a good example

Comment: Thanks for the link, was already in my favorites (once our Azure Devops is ready ^^)

In the meanwhile I've follow your proposal and all was ok except the Invoke-ASCmd. 
Invoke-ASCmd : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I even try adding my connection string (as mention on top of my question) , no success. did you succeed in implementing a solution?